# Defined static method is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, oop, google-maps-api-3

I made a static method `geocode()`. But when I'm calling it I get an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I can't wrap my head around on what it is that I'm doing wrong here.

```
'use strict';

var gMap = (function (window, document, Gmap) {
    var gMap;

    Gmap.geocode({ 'address': 'Paris, France' }, function (results, status) {
        if (status !== Gmap.geocodeStatus.OK) {
            throw new Error('Geocode was unsuccessful: ' + status);
        }

        gMap = new Gmap(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
            center: results[0].geometry.location,
            zoom: 10
        });
    });

    return gMap;
}(window, document, Gmap));

function Gmap(element, options) {
    if (!(typeof window.google === 'object' && typeof window.google.maps === 'object')) {
        throw Error('The Google Maps JavaScript API v3 library is required.');
    }

    this.googleMap = new google.maps.Map(element, options);
    this.currentLocation = options.center;
    this.markers = [];
}

Gmap.geocode = function (geocoderRequest, callback) {
    googleGeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    googleGeocoder.geocode(geocoderRequest, function (results, status) {
        callback(results, status);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to *[function hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting)*. What is happening in your code is that your `function Gmap(...)` is being hoisted to the top and parsed *before* your `var gMap = ...`, however your `Gmap.geocode` is declared after your `var gMap` declaration and thus doesn't exist at that point.

To fix this, simply declare `Gmap.geocode` *above* `var gMap = ...`:

```
Gmap.geocode = function ( ... ) { ... } ;

var gMap = ... ;
```

Answer (score 0):

invert yout code.
put the Gmap definition above `var gMap = ...`